# Faithful irreducible representation of a finite $p$-group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

I want to solve the following exercise in the representation theory field:

A finite $p$-group $G$ has a faithful irreducible representation over an algebraically closed field whose characteristic is not $p$ if and only if the center of $G$ is cyclic.

I can prove the above statement over the field of complex numbers (it is Theorem 2.32 of the book "Character theory" by M. Isaacs).

Also, I can prove that if a finite group $G$ has a faithful irreducible representation over an algebraically closed field, then the center of $G$ is cyclic. So, I just want to prove that if a finite $p$-group $G$ has the cyclic center, then it has a faithful irreducible representation over an algebraically closed field whose characteristic is not $p$.

I think that the proof that is mentioned in the book "Character theory", can be used for any fields, because I do not see any facts about $\mathbb{C}$ using in the proof. Actually, I don't know why the assumptions "over an algebraically closed field whose characteristic is not $p$" are necessary in this case.

Thank you so much for your guidance.

Comment: You certainly need the characteristic not to be $p$.  No nontrivial $p$-group has a faithful irreducible representation over a field of characteristic $p$. You don't need the field to be algebraically closed, but you can assume without loss of generality that it is, because an irreducible representation over any field decomposes into algebraically conjugate representations when you extend the field.

Comment: @DerekHolt: I got the point. Thank you so much.